# How to get all attributes of a given product?

Tags: product, product-attribute, magento-2.1

I want to get all the attributes which are not empty for a given product. Tried various suggestions in the web, but didn't work,

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can get attribute in list page

e.g if machinemaker is you atttribute then in manage attribute it will be 
represented as machine_maker attribute code and you can get this using :
$_product->getMachineMaker();

and if you wannt non empty attribute value then use this like below.it will display the attribute value if it is not empty.

if($_product->getMachineMaker())
 { echo "

**Machine Make :** ".$_product->getMachineMaker()."

" ; }

Answer (score 0):

I have written the play script to fetch product attributes value that are not empty and it worked.

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app('');
$product_id = 8;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 
    if(!is_null($attribute->getFrontendLabel()) && ((string)$attribute- >getFrontend()->getValue($product) != '')){
        $attributeLabel = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);         
        echo $attributeLabel . '-' . $value; echo "<br />";       
    }
}
```